# quick sort in c how to change pivot

Tags: c

***HELLO EVERYBODY I NEED YOUR HELP PLEASE ,I WANT TO CHANGE THE PIVOT IN THE MIDDLE OF TABLE AND I DONT KNOW HOW ? I modified the code i think it is more lisible now i really need your help  ***

```
void quickSort(int *arr, int elements) {

#define  MAX_LEVELS  300

int  piv, beg[MAX_LEVELS], end[MAX_LEVELS], i=0, L, R, swap ;

beg[0]=0;
end[0]=elements;
while (i>=0) {
L=beg[i]; 
R=end[i]-1;
if (L<R) 
{
  piv=arr[L];
  while (L<R) 
  {
    while (arr[R]>=piv && L<R) 
      R--; 
    if (L<R)
      arr[L++]=arr[R];
    while (arr[L]<=piv && L<R)
     L++; 
    if (L<R) arr[R--]=arr[L];
  }
  arr[L]=piv;
  beg[i+1]=L+1;
  end[i+1]=end[i];
  end[i++]=L;
  if (end[i]-beg[i]>end[i-1]-beg[i-1]) 
  {
    swap=beg[i];
    beg[i]=beg[i-1];
    beg[i-1]=swap;
    swap=end[i]; 
    end[i]=end[i-1];
    end[i-1]=swap;
  }
  }
  else 
  {
    i--;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Owww!  My ears!  Please do not shout like that.

Comment: And please don't write code like that. Whitespace is a good thing.

Comment: ..as are newlines.  Multiple statements on one line are difficult to read and difficult to debug - if you're single-stepping through with your debugger, how will you know which statement on a line is, say, generating a segfault?  Stop coding for economy and start coding for debuggability.

Comment: i changed it now please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
void quickSort(int *arr, int elements) {

#define  MAX_LEVELS  300

int  piv, beg[MAX_LEVELS], end[MAX_LEVELS], i=0, L, R, swap ;

beg[0]=0;
end[0]=elements;
while (i>=0) {
L=beg[i]; 
R=end[i]-1;
if (L<R) 
{
  piv=arr[L];
  while (L<R) 
  {
    while (arr[R]>=piv && L<R) 
      R--; 
    if (L<R)
      arr[L++]=arr[R];
    while (arr[L]<=piv && L<R)
     L++; 
    if (L<R) arr[R--]=arr[L];
  }
  arr[L]=piv;
  beg[i+1]=L+1;
  end[i+1]=end[i];
  end[i++]=L;
  if (end[i]-beg[i]>end[i-1]-beg[i-1]) 
  {
    swap=beg[i];
    beg[i]=beg[i-1];
    beg[i-1]=swap;
    swap=end[i]; 
    end[i]=end[i-1];
    end[i-1]=swap;
  }
}
else 
{
  i--;
}
}
}
```